# what if binary had three states like {0,1,2} instead if {0,1} then how many possible combinations we could have?

Tags: combinations, binary

so if binary can hold two states i.e {0,1} then total combinations we could get is 2^n. what if binary had three states {0,1,2} then what should be formula? 3^n?

Comment: It wouldn't be called binary any longer, because that name implies specifically that there are two symbols to choose from. Depending on the context, any one of [these Wikipedia articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) (I'd go with article number 1 or 3) may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in that case it is not called binary, but ternary. Think as follows:

> For a word with $n-$letters you have $3$ possible choices for the first letter, $3$ for the second, $3$ for the third etc. So, since you have $n$ terms you have in total:
>   $$\underbrace{3\cdot3\cdot3\dots3}_{n\text{ times}}=3^n$$

*In general, try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and give more context in your questions. It would be also advisavble to show us your thoughts and what have you tried!*